# Saving an XLS file locally

Tags: python, plone, xls

I am having a very strange problem.  I have an event set for the modification of a content type I created that has a file field.  The file that will be uploaded is an XLS file and I want to save a copy locally.

Now, here's where it gets strange.  When I am in foreground mode, when the event is triggered the file saves without any problems.  However, when I run the instance normally (./bin/instance start) I get an IOError (See below).  Yet, regardless of if I am in foreground or background mode, I tried to create a test 'Hello World' .txt file that works just fine.

Any thoughts?  Much appreciation in advance!

Patrick

I am using Plone 4.0.1 on an SLES 10 server.

The error:

```
...        
Module patrick.cm.content.events, line 95, in q_changed
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'process/test-file.xls'
```

The code:

```
def q_changed(obj, event):
    if obj.xls_file.getSize() > 0:                       
        filename = getattr(obj.xls_file, 'filename')

        save_questionnaire = open('process/%s' % (filename), 'wb')     #Line 95 
        q_data = str(obj.xls_file.data)   
        save_questionnaire.write(q_data)
        save_questionnaire.close()
```

This code works:

```
def q_changed(obj, event):
    save_questionnaire = open('process/test.txt', 'wb')     
    save_questionnaire.write('Hello World!')
    save_questionnaire.close()
```

Comment: Does the value of `os.getcwd()` change between the working instance and the failing instance?

Comment: Always use absolute paths and make sure the user the process is running as has access to the location you're writing to.

Comment: There is a difference in the working directory between an instance running in fg and an instance running with bin/instance start. This is likely to be part of your issue.

Comment: Yes!  You are right.  Running in background mode has a CWD of ../parts/instance while in fg mode the CWD is the root of the my plone instance directory.  Will use absolute directories from now on!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreground mode and background mode have different working directories.

Solution: Use absolute paths!